# sails:how to convert array of array to json object

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

I'm trying to read my uploaded xlsx find and trying to convert array of array to json key value pair object.
so i'm trying below snippet

```
var fs = uploadedFiles[0].fd;
var xlsxRows = require('xlsx-rows');
var rows = xlsxRows(fs);
var json = JSON.stringify(rows);
console.log(json);
```

It shows result like array of arrays

```
 [ [ 'Name', 'Age', 'Address' ],
  [ 'Raj', '43', 'trichy' ],
  [ 'Krthi', '23', 'trichy' ],
  [ 'vel', '24', 'trichy' ] ]
```

but i need to store this as a key vale pair of json object.

```
[{'Name':'Raj',
'Age':'43',
'Addess':'tichy'},
{'Name':'Krthi',
'Age':'23',
'Addess':'tichy'},
{'Name':'Vel',
'Age':'24',
'Addess':'tichy'}
]
```

how can i achieve this..can any one help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either re-parse the resulting rows and build the JSON yourself

```
// your existing code
var fs = uploadedFiles[0].fd;
var xlsxRows = require('xlsx-rows');
var rows = xlsxRows(fs);

// retrieve headers (i.e. remove first row)
var headers = rows.shift();

// then build the json for each row
var result = rows.map(function(row) {
    var jsonRow = {};
    row.forEach(function(cellValue, cellIndex) { 
        jsonRow[headers[cellIndex]] = cellValue;
    });
    return jsonRow;
});
```

Or you can simply use a module that does it for you, like [`xlsx-json`](https://github.com/zxzsaga/xlsx-json);

**UPDATE**

If I execute the above code with your sample data, I get exactly the output you're expecting, namely (output obtained with `JSON.stringify(result)`):

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Raj",
    "Age": "43",
    "Address": "trichy"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Krthi",
    "Age": "23",
    "Address": "trichy"
  },
  {
    "Name": "vel",
    "Age": "24",
    "Address": "trichy"
  }
]
```

Comment: It shows an error like  TypeError: Object [["Name","Age","Address"],["Martin","43","trichy"],["Krthi","23","trichy"],["vel","24","trichy"]] has no method 'shift'

Comment: My bad, I used the wrong variable, it should be `rows` instead of `json`.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a way. Anyway, you can still use the above code to make it work the way you like.

Comment: Val its again store as a json array not an object.I need json object as a result.please help.

Comment: Not sure about it, works fine for me, see the output I get above, which matches what you're expecting.