# Elasticsearch: how to store all json objects dynamically

Tags: json, elasticsearch, sails.js

I'm trying to store all Json objects through elasticsearch.

```
client.create({
                index: 'index',
                type: 'type',
                id:"1"
                body:result[0]
                },function (error,response)
                   {
                     if (error) 
                     {
                        console.log('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
                      } 
                      else 
                      {
                        console.log('All is well');
                      }
            });
```

In this  `result[0]` I'm getting my first value of a Json object but I need to store all Json objects dynamically.

The output which i'm getting is:

```
  -> POST http://localhost:9200/index/type/1?op_type=create
  {
    "Name": "Martin",
    "Age": "43",
    "Address": "trichy"
  }
  <- 201
  {
    "_index": "index",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "1",
    "_version": 4,
    "created": true
  }
```

But I need an output like this:

```
 -> POST http://localhost:9200/index/type/1?op_type=create
      {
        "Name": "Martin",
        "Age": "43",
        "Address": "trichy"
      },
      {
        "Name": "vel",
        "Age": "23",
        "Address": "chennai"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ajay",
        "Age": "23",
        "Address": "chennai"
      }
      <- 201
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_version": 4,
        "created": true
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to use the [bulk endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-bulk) in order to send many documents at the same time.

The body contains two rows per document, the first row contains the index, type and id of the document and the document itself is in the next row. Rinse and repeat for each document.

```
client.bulk({
  body: [
    // action description
    { index:  { _index: 'index', _type: 'type', _id: 1 } },
     // the document to index
    { Name: 'Martin', Age: 43, Address: 'trichy' },
    { index:  { _index: 'index', _type: 'type', _id: 2 } },
    { Name: 'vel', Age: 23, Address: 'chennai' },
    { index:  { _index: 'index', _type: 'type', _id: 3 } },
    { Name: 'ajay', Age: 23, Address: 'chennai' }
  ]
}, function (err, resp) {
  // ...
});
```

I suspect your `result` array is the JSON you get from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349694/sailshow-to-convert-array-of-array-to-json-object) from yesterday. If so, then you can build the bulk body dynamically, like this:

```
var body = [];
result.forEach(function(row, id) {
    body.push({ index:  { _index: 'index', _type: 'type', _id: (id+1) } });
    body.push(row);
});
```

Then you can use the `body` in your `bulk` call like this:

```
client.bulk({
  body: body
}, function (err, resp) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Great! Always glad to help!

Comment: Hi Val, how can i create mapping before bulk upload.Is this possible to do? I don't know how to do please guide me to do this.

Comment: I've answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451702/elasticsearch-how-can-i-create-mapping-before-upload-json-data-into-elasticsear).