# Elasticsearch: how can i create mapping before upload json data into Elasticsearch

Tags: json, node.js, elasticsearch, sails.js

I'm trying to create mapping before uploading json data into elasticsearch.
I don't know how to implement mapping before uploading json data in sails.js

This is my bulkupload snippet

```
     var body = [];
      //row is json data
        rows.forEach(function(row, id) {
             body.push({ index:  { _index: 'testindex', _type: 'testtype', _id: (id+1) } });
             body.push(row);
        })  
    client.bulk({
                    body: body
                }, function (err, resp) {
                        if (err) 
                        {
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                       }
                      else 
                      { 
                            console.log("All Is Well");
                      }
      });
```

I want to create mapping before data upload.can any one know how to create mapping in sails.

my Json object

```
 [ { Name: 'paranthn', Age: '43', Address: 'trichy' },
      { Name: 'Arthick', Age: '23', Address: 'trichy' },
      { Name: 'vel', Age: '24', Address: 'trichy' } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before making your `client.bulk()` call you first need to make another `client.indices.putMapping()` call like this in order to save the correct mapping for the data you're about to send via the `bulk` call:

```
client.indices.putMapping({
   "index": "testindex",
   "type": "testtype",
   "body": {
      "testtype": {
          "properties": {
              "your_int_field": {
                  "type": "integer"
              },
              "your_string_field": {
                  "type": "string"
              },
              "your_double_field": {
                  "type": "double"
              },
              // your other fields
          }
      }
   }
}, function (err, response) {
   // from this point on, if you don't get any error, you may call bulk.
});
```

Remember that all these calls are asynchronous, so be careful to only call `bulk` once `putMapping` has returned successfully.

Comment: Hi val it works fine for me. but i json object returs everythig as a string but in my properties i need to set property as a integer how can i acheive that.

Comment: The number of fields in the JSON may be dynamic. Then how can I do mapping for this ? i have updated sample json data in my question please refer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need [PutMapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html).

Comment: But i need  to do mapping in sails.js before that bulk upload functionality.Is this possible to do?