# Elastic-search: How can i map json data having dynamic number of fields

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm working on a application for that  i need to map json data for storing in Elasticsearch. The number of fields in json data is dynamic.then how can i do mapping for this scenario.

mapping Snippet

```
var fs = uploadedFiles[0].fd;
var xlsxRows = require('xlsx-rows');
var rows = xlsxRows(fs);
console.log(rows);


     client.indices.putMapping({
            "index": "testindex",
            "type": "testtype",
            "body": {
                "testtype": {
                    "properties": {

                        "Field 1": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "Field 3": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "Field 2":{
                            "type":"string"
                        } .....
                       //Don't know how many fields are in json object.
                  } 
            }
        }
    }, function (err, response) {
            if(err){
                console.log("error");
            }
            console.log("REAPONCE")
            console.log(response);                                  

      });
```

This is my sample json data 
//result of rows

```
 [
  { Name: 'paranthn', Age: '43', Address: 'trichy' },
  { Name: 'Arthick', Age: '23', Address: 'trichy' },
  { Name: 'vel', Age: '24', Address: 'trichy' } //property fields
  ]
```

> NOTE: The number of property fields are dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean by "number"? I only see three fields named `Name`, `Age` and `Address`. Do you have other fields that you are expecting?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how many fields in json object.The fields are dynamically changing for every file upload.

Comment: It's still not clear if you mean that one document might contain other fields than `Name`, `Age` and `Address` or if your documents contain an array (i.e. `[...]`) of several objects as shown above and you don't know how many elements that array might contain.

Comment: Yes. document might contain other fields than Name, Age and Address.

Answer (score 0):

ES will always make its best efforts to infer the correct type for the fields in your documents that have no mapping defined and [set sensible defaults](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html).

A mapping is only necessary if you need to apply some special treatment to certain fields other than the set defaults, like specifying an indexing analyzer, a search analyzer, whether string fields need to be analyzed or not, specifying sub-fields with a different analyzer, etc.

If you don't need any of this, then you can let ES infer the mapping of your documents.

Comment: Is this possible to read json rows and assign this  rows into property fields?please help

Comment: Whevever you discover a new field that hasn't been mapped yet, you can definitely call `putMapping` to add that new field to your mapping, **before** indexing the data.

Comment: Is this possible to do foreach loop to pick the field Name from json object and assign that name into/property fields?

Comment: Yes, and you can do it while you're parsing your data as we saw in [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349694/sailshow-to-convert-array-of-array-to-json-object)

Comment: How can i pick field names seperatly from my json object.I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to manage the mapping by yourself if 1) you don't know the field names in advance and 2) you have no ideas of their type in advance either. Why not let ES manage the mapping?

Comment: Yes your correct val but  the field names contains in json object.I want to get field name from json object and pass this name to property field in putmapping function.

Comment: So, what's your motivation to not let ES take care of your mapping?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89133/discussion-between-martin-and-val).